# Following the result of pressing a submit button in Python Mechanize

Tags: python, browser, mechanize

So I have an authenticated site that I want to access via the mechanize module. I'm able to log in, and then go to the page I want. However, because the page recognizes that mechanize doesn't have javascript enabled, it wants me to click a submit button to get redirected to a non javascript part of the site. How can I simply click the button and then read the contents of the page that follows that?

Or, is there a way to trick it into thinking that my javascript is enables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if that submit button is really a submit input element of the form, and the redirection works as usual form submit action, and provided that it's the only form in the page, your mechanize browser instance is `br`, following should work

```
br.select_form(nr=0) # select the first form
br.submit()
```

afaik, there's no simple or moderately possible way, how to emulate javascript in mechanize, possible workarounds depend on what is javascript exactly doing