# Submitting a form in mechanize

Tags: python, forms, mechanize

I'm having issues submitting the result of a form submission (I can submit a form, but I can't submit the form on the page that follows the first).

I have:

```
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
browser.open('https://www.example.com/login')
browser.select_form(nr=0)

browser.form['j_username'] = 'username'
browser.form['j_password'] = 'password'
req = browser.submit()
```

This works, as `print req` results in

`

```
<body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
    <noscript>
        <p>
            <strong>Note:</strong> Since your browser does not support JavaScript,
            you must press the Continue button once to proceed.
        </p>
    </noscript>

    <form action="https://www.example.com/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST" method="post">
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="RelayState" value="cookie:95ca495c"/>                

            <input type="hidden" name="SAMLResponse" value="really long encoded value"/>                
        </div>
        <noscript>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Continue"/>
            </div>
        </noscript>
    </form>

</body>
```

`

But I get errors when I try to use `req.select_form(nr=0)`

I assume this is probably from something along the lines of how mechanize returns objects from `submit()` and that I'm going about this the wrong way.

Any input or guidance would be appreciated :)

Comment: didn't you forget to submit this first form, to obtain the login form? (`browser.submit()` after `browser.select_form(nr=0)`)

Comment: No, I set req = browser.submit(), which submits the first form, right?

Comment: i thought that you get the real login form after submitting the first redirecting form.. so there is another form in this page? your question resembles me [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901218/following-the-result-of-pressing-a-submit-button-in-python-mechanize), which is obviously yours as well :)

Comment: The first page has one form, and when I submit it I get the second page (which just has a Submit button). I want to be able to submit the second page as well, that's what I can't seem to get. It doesn't like that mechanize doesn't do javascript, so it want's "me" to click a button to verify I guess

Comment: so why do you submit only once? if you get some error, please describe it

Comment: @parker ah, maybe i get the problem :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try again `browser.select_form(nr=0)` instead of `req.select_form(nr=0)`. (after submitting or clicking a link or so, the new response is considered as an actual browser page - like in a browser :) )