# Python Mechanize Submit Button on NIH Website

Tags: python, button, submit, mechanize

I'm using mechanize on python 2.7.3. I'm looking for help on hitting the submit button on [NIH's gene website](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene).

The button is an actual button element surrounded by divs and not inside any form field.

```
<button id="search" type="submit" class="button_search nowrap" cmd="go">Search</button>
```

So far in examples and what I've seen online, submit buttons usually have a name or a label which mechanize can select for, or are in a form so I can do br.submit().

How would I hit submit on this one?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956280/submitting-a-form-in-mechanize

Comment: No, the submit button in my case is not inside a form. I believe this renders br.select_form() useless.

Answer (score 2):

The button does not submit the for directly, but instead triggers a JavascriptEvent, which will eventually load the search page. This explains why the button works in your browser even though it is not inside the form.

`mechanize` cannot run JS code, so you will not be able to "click" on the button directly using `mechanize`.

Is there a reason you cannot just open the target URL? These seem pretty straightforward, even  on the advanced search form, for example:

```
term = '("31"[Chromosome]) AND "000"[Disease/Phenotype]'
q = urllib.urlencode({'term': term})
response = mechanize.urlopen('http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene?%s' % q)
```

If this does not work for you, you'll have to fall back on a solution which does support JavaScript, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606550/watir-vs-selenium-vs-sahi for pointers.