# how to submit after filling out a form with mechanize

Tags: forms, submit, mechanize

What I am trying to do is really simple. Here is the code:

```
import re
from mechanize import Browser
br = Browser()
br.open("http://adreskodu.dask.gov.tr/" )

br.select_form( nr = 0 )
br.form.set_value(['1'],name='tip')
br.submit()
```

As you can see, the website first shows up with two radio buttons, and then after selecting the left radiobuttion via the br.form.set_value call and submit, I expect to access the new forms with mechanize that would appear normally if you were doing this on a browser. 
What I would expect is a new form with more controls (if you go to the website and click on the left radiobutton, you will see what i am talking about).
However, I either dont do the submit correctly or don't know how to access the newly generated form that just came into being after clicking the very first radio button. 
Ideally, i would want to re-find the newly created form and select the drop down menus and such. Is this a javascript issue I am encountering?
Thanks

Comment: I read the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177389/python-mechanize-submit-button-on-nih-website?rq=1 and think that it is the mechanize that cannot run JS, but would be interested what the experts here would say

Comment: You really can't use mechanize for Javascript. There are alternatives that you can use, though I'm not a Python programmer I think Selenium Webdriver http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/ has Python bindings.