# How to click with mechanize in python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, mechanize

i have a form which is used for authentication.  but in this form there are no submit button but it has used an `<input>` as a button . now i am confused how to click this type of button with MECHANIZE.

[image: page details]

till now i had done this:

```
import urllib
import re
import mechanize
from base64 import b64encode
```

and can this be done in Java script?

```
br = mechanize.Browser()


response = br.open("http://xyz.com");
#print response.code
#print response.geturl()

br.select_form("login")
br.form['j_username'] = 'user'
br.form['j_password'] = 'pass'
```

Comment: `br.form.submit()` doesn't work?

Comment: there is no method of br.form.sumbit()
but after selecting the form we can submit the form by br.form() but it is giving this error:
<response_seek_wrapper at 0x2d693a0 whose wrapped object = <closeable_response at 0x2d86fd0 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x02D7DA30>>>

Comment: Sorry, I meant `br.submit`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3956280/198633) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4727364/198633)

Comment: br.submit() should return another webpage but it returning some different thing which i have described in above comment.

Comment: That's not an error. Read the response - it's a filelike object.

response = br.form.submit()
html = response.read()

Comment: I'll make an answer so people can find it if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

That's not an error. Read the response - it's a filelike object.

```
br.select_form("login")
br.form['j_username'] = 'xyz'
br.form['j_password'] = 'pass'
pag2 = br.submit()
html = pag2.read()
print html
```

Comment: @MilchePatern Tempted to PEP8 it. ;)

Comment: the page that is coming after submitting is the same page with error..
onclicking the button some javescript code runs.. 
is mechanize support the javascript in it?

Comment: @RATHI Mechanize has no javascript engine. you can often get around javascript by just posting/getting from the url where the javascript would have.

Answer (score 1):

This *is* a submit button. A submit button in HTML is by definition an `<input>` element of type `submit`.